# Error while reversing string in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have this code to reverse a string using 8086 ALP. But the code does not work as intended and gets into a infinite loop or prints some random charecter.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
String1 DB "Assembly Language Program$"
Length dw $-String1-1

.code
Main proc
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX

MOV SI, Offset String1
MOV CX, Length  
ADD SI, CX

Back: MOV DL, [SI]
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H
DEC SI
LOOP Back  

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
Main endp
End main
```

Comment: Make the stack bigger and try again.

Comment: Do you get any warning / error message during assembly? I cannot assemble your code neither with latest masm32, nor with legacy masm 5.1 Could you provide your masm version and the command line to assemble?

Comment: Actually i was using emu8086

Comment: OK, i get it now, because `length` is a masm/tasm reserved word to compute the size of a data like for `foo db 42 dup (?)` -> 42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has 2 issues:

1. `$` stands for "the offset of the current compiling instruction", and it can be used in some offset arithmetic, but the way you are declaring your `length` data is not doing what you think. Actually, `length` is containing the offset of itself, minus the offset of `String1`, minus 1. The common way to use `$` to compute a length is by using an `equ` constant right after the string declaration, like:

   ```
   String1 DB "Assembly Language Program$"
   Length EQU $-String1
   ```

   That is, the `MOV CX, Length` will load `CX` with the length of the string and not a memory offset. An `EQU` does not take any place in the resulting program. If anyway you would like to have a place in memory with the string length and not only defining it at assembly time, you can do

   ```
   String1 DB "Assembly Language Program$"
   strl EQU $-String1 
   Length DW strl    ;the initialized data will be the string length, not an offset
   ```
2. your code start to reverse the string 1 byte too long, as for a 1 byte string you don't have to add anything, so e.g a `DEC SI` will correct the offset.

The following (slightly) modified program do what you want:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
String1 DB "Assembly Language Program$"
Length equ $-String1-1

.code
Main proc  
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX

MOV SI, Offset String1
MOV CX, Length  
ADD SI, CX
DEC SI

Back: MOV DL, [SI]
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H
DEC SI
LOOP Back  

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
Main endp
End main
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is

```
ADD SI, CX
```

whereas you
have to

```
MOV SI, CX
```

I would like to say that i am not familiar with this kind of implementation and i cannot help more. But take a look to this code which is also reverse a String.

```
TITLE reverse
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:data
CODE SEGMENT


START:
    MOV AX,data
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV SI,0 ; pointer
LENGTH:
    CMP message[SI],'$'
    JE NEXT

    INC SI
    JMP LENGTH
NEXT:
    MOV CX,SI
    DEC SI
CHANGE:
    MOV DL,message[SI]

    MOV AH,02H  
    INT 21H     

    DEC SI
    LOOP CHANGE
END:
    MOV AH,4CH 
        int 21h 


CODE ENDS

DATA SEGMENT 

    MSG DB 10,13,"$"
    message DB 'Assembly Language Program$'

DATA ENDS

END START
```

Comment: in this case `SI` must point to the actual address of a character, while a `MOV SI, CX` will set `SI` to a length

Comment: Yes but since the stack is empty, i think that the length of the String has the same value with the ip of the stack. Am i right?
Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, as I was suspecting, the issue is in the `dw` instead of an `equ` declaration of the length resulting of a wrong address computing to begin the reversing. Another problem is that the given code is for emu8086 and cannot compile with masm. See my answer.