# Unable to reverse string in 8086 MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

I've written some 8086 assembly code to reverse a string. I'm relatively new to assembly so please bear with me.

The logic is that I define a string called 'str1'. I move this into the *SI* Register. Suppose string 'str1' is *"Hello$"*, then I load the address of 'str1'+5 into *SI*. Now, I load an address, say 5000 into *DI*. And I load each character from *SI* into *DI* and everytime I increment SI and decrement SI till 5 times.

Here is the code

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
str db "Hello$"
data ends
code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
cld
mov cx,5h
mov bx,5h
lea si,str
add si,5
mov di,5000h
l1:mov bx,[si]
mov [di],bx
dec si
inc di
loop l1
hlt
code ends
end
```

---

I get an absolute garbage value when I access location 5000. Plz help thanks

Comment: How can you tell what's at location 5000?

Comment: Characters are 1 byte each, but you are processing 2 bytes. PS: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester How am I processing 1 byte? Should I use AL instead of AX then?

Comment: You don't even use `AX`, you are using `BX`. And yeah, you should use `BL` (for example).

Comment: I have to wonder if you've done any kind of searching or research on your own. This question has been posted at least five times in the last two days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while reversing string in 8086](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949662/error-while-reversing-string-in-8086)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost good, you only need an auxiliary string (if such thing is allowed) :

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
str db "Hello$"
aux db "     $"       ;AUXILIARY STRING.
data ends
code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
cld
mov cx,5h
mov bx,5h
lea si,str
add si,4              ;0..4 = 5.
lea di,aux            ;POINT TO AUXILIARY.
l1:mov bl,[si]        ;YEAH, LET'S USE
mov [di],bl           ;"BL" INSTEAD OF "BX".
dec si
inc di
loop l1
hlt
code ends
end
```